# What is $A \cap (A\cup B)'$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

What is $A\cap(A\cup B)'$?

I am not sure how to solve these using Venn diagrams. I tried de Morgan, but I am not sure, please clarify.

Comment: Do you  mean $A \cap (A\cup B)'$?

Comment: yes i mean this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, by way of contradiction, that  $\ x \in A \cap (A \cup B)'  $.

Then, $\ x \in (A \cup B)'\ $, therefore $\ x \notin A \cup B,\ $ therefore $\ x \notin A \ $ and $ x \notin B.\ $

Since $ x \notin A, \ x \ $ cannot be in a set which is the intersection of $A$ and another set.

Therefore, $ x \notin A \cap (A \cup B)' $.

We have shown that there don't exist any elements in $A \cap (A \cup B)',\ $ i.e. $A \cap (A \cup B)' $ is the empty set, $\ \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

$A\cap(A\cup B)'\ =\ A\cap(A'\cap B')\ =\ (A\cap A')\cap B'\ =\ \varnothing\cap B'\ =\varnothing$

Answer (score 0):

$(A\cup B)'$ is anything other than A or B.
Hence, $A \cap (A\cup B)'$ is $\phi$.